# Error on adding extension to FirefoxProfile

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon, browser-extension

After searching I found a way to add extension to the Firefox via `.FirefoxProfile()`. However, the same solution is mentioned everywhere.

I don't understand why I am facing an error. Here is the code:

```
 String firebugFilePath = "C:\FF_addons\firebug.xpi";
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        try {
            profile.addExtension(new File(firebugFilePath));
            // Add more FF addons if required 
        } catch (IOException err) {                
        }
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Error I am facing is on the 4th line: `incompatible types: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File cannot be converted to java.io.File`.

Comment: Make sure you've imported java.io.File

Comment: Perfect! that works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are importing the wrong `File` class.

change your

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File
```

to

```
import java.io.File
```